# Php form submit check

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP code that adds data to MySQL table. I need to check if 2 records don't exist and then to proceed to add them.

Here is my code but never else statement works. Here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$username=$_POST['username'];
$imerominia=$_POST['imerominia'];
$diarkia=$_POST['diarkia'];

$queryAQ = $db->query("SELECT username,imerominia FROM sdit WHERE $username 
= '$username' AND imerominia = '$imerominia'");
$wres = $queryAQ->results();

if(!empty($wres))
{
$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO sdit (username,imerominia,diarkia) VALUES('$username','$imerominia','$diarkia')");



    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Successfully Added"); location.href="account.php"';
    echo '</script>';
 } 
 else  
 {


echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("DATE ALLREADY EXISTS"); location.href="account.php"';
    echo '</script>';

}
}
```

Comment: what does `$queryAQ->results();` return if there are no results?

Comment: i need just a javascript alert so i dont want to do anyhting!

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. We don't know what `$wres` can be, so we can't help.

Comment: just want to check if 2 values exist. imerominia and username values. If exist both i dont want to continue the form submit

Comment: yes. I can see that. But unless we know what the (likely custom made) method `results()` returns _we cannot answer_.

Comment: this is wrong by the way: `... FROM sdit WHERE $username = ...`

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: JavaScript alerts are always the worst possible way to surface these sorts of problems. Try using a hidden `<div>` you can display on an error or something like that. You have a lot more control over the style, presentation and function of those, plus they don't jam up the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have some logical error in your `SELECT` query where you are comparing

```
$username = '$username'
```

As per my understanding, this will never be `true`. And that might be one of the reason `!empty($wres)` evaluated as `true` and always falling into `false`.

So, correct SQL should be

```
SELECT username,imerominia FROM sdit WHERE username = '$username' AND imerominia = '$imerominia'
```

But, I would rather insist your to use PreparedStatement, to avoid such error and SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

if(!empty($wres)) is always evaluating to true which is why the else statement never fires

Check what

```
$queryAQ->results();
```

returns if it is empty and change your if statement to look for that